# Inappropriate I/O control operation

Tags: perl, syntax-error

my question is rather simple,. but can't resolve "Inappropriate I/O control operation" error which I'm receiving after execution of my Perl script.

```
#!C:/Perl/bin/perl.exe -w
use strict;

my $file = "D:/file.csv";
open(my $data, '<', $file) or die "Could not open '$file' $!\n";
while (my $line = <$data>) {
    chomp $line; 
    my @fields = split "," , $line;
    print $fields[1]."\n";
}
```

any idea, what I'm doing wrong? I'm running this script on ActiveState perl on windows7

Comment: I see nothing obviously wrong with your code. Can you show us the full error message, and tell us which line it says the error is on?

Comment: What is `D:`? Is it a network share?

Comment: "after execution"?  what is executing this script?

Comment: Are you sure the script says `open or die $!;` and not `open && die $!`?

Comment: @Illmari: Its actually only visible whilst debugging the script using PerlDevKit in KOmodo

Comment: @borodin: D:/ is the D: drive on my PC

Comment: @ysth: Its actually only visible whilst debugging the script using PerlDevKit in KOmodo

Comment: @taiko : Your comment to ysth conforms with my answer. The only time `$!` means something is immediately after failure, so the value seen through the debugger should not be considered in the event of a successful `open`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My suspicion is that your script is printing the value of `$!` through an `open && die $!` or `open or die $!; print $!;`.

Here is a minimal script that reproduces the same issue on Windows:

```
C:\> perl -e "open my $fh, '<', 'file_that_opens' && die $!"
Inappropriate I/O control operation
```

And here is what happens on *nix:

```
$ perl -e 'open my $fh, "<", "file_that_opens" && die $!'
Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

---

### This behavior is documented

According to [`perldoc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html), `$!` is only meaningful in the event of a failure. When `open` is called, it sets a value for `$!`, but the value is only useful if the `open` did not succeed:

> ... `$!` is meaningful only *immediately* after a **failure**:
>
> ```
> if (open my $fh, "<", $filename) {
>               # Here $! is meaningless.
>     ...
> }
> else {        # ONLY here is $! meaningful.
>     ...       # Already here $! might be meaningless.
> }
> # Since here we might have either success or failure,
> # $! is meaningless.
> ```
>
> Here, *meaningless* means that `$!` may be unrelated to the outcome of
>   the `open()` operator.